# BizTalk 2010 Inbound 997 Routing Errors

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

In the system I'm working on, BizTalk 2010 sends out transactions to trading partners and we receive 997s. Every time we receive a 997, I'm seeing a routing error in the administration console.

In BizTalk 2006 R2, 997s were received by the EdiReceive pipeline, the reports were updated (if enabled) and then the 997 was terminated if there weren't any explicit subscriptions defined. In other words, the 997 was never forwarded to the message box.

So my question is, is there something in the new trading partner management piece in BizTalk 2010 that makes it work like it used to, or is this a behavior change in BizTalk 2010 and now I have to explicitly deal with inbound 997s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to configure send port to get 997.....you need to use  BTS.MessageType == http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/X12#X12_997_Root.

This represents a behavior change from previous versions.

Comment: So you're saying this is a behavior change from previous versions?

Comment: That's bizarre. Looks like I get to build something to process the 997s so they don't create bogus routing errors.

Comment: These are inbound 997s coming from my trading partners, not outbound 997s. I want to receive them for EDI reporting, but I don't want them to go to the message box.