# How to get EDI 997 instead of TA1 in BT2010?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi, purchase-order

I'm testing (simulating receipt) of PO/850 on BizTalk 2010 by dropping an EDI in a file receive.  I get two files output, one is a TA1 and one is the 850. (In the real world, I will send the 997 back to the party that sent me the 850.)

I have a Send Port defined to go to file system, with filter: 
`BTS.ReceivePortName == rp_partner_850`.  In the directory associated with that SendPort is where I see both the 850 and the TA1.

In the Party/Agreement in BTAdmin, on the Parter->MyCompany tab, then the "Acknowledgments" section, I have checked "997 expected" and not checked "TA1 Expected".

I'm also unclear why I need to select the "Send Ports" in the Party/Agreement tool.  How does that interplay with filters on the Send Ports.

I tried setting up a second send port to a second disk directory, and on that one I set filter to this: `BTS.MessageType == http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/X12#X12_997_Root`, as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977732/biztalk-2010-inbound-997-routing-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made quite a few changes, so not sure exactly which one got it working. I followed videos 2-4 found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/gg153513

I'm still getting the TA1s, and will work on that next, but now I'm getting 997s in a separate SendPort.

I added new send port sp_997_Test with the filter as described in the question above, and specified that in the "MyCompany->Partner" tab of the agreement under Send Ports.

I also setup the "Local Host Settings" on the "Partner->MyCompany" and put "850-Purchase-Order..." in the ST1 column, and the Partner Value in the GS2 column.